# Best way to perform a distinct on +5M records table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application using an AWS Aurora SQL postgres 10 DB that expects +5M records per day on a table. The application will be running on a kubernetes environment with ~5 pods.
One of the applications requirements is to export a method to build an object with all the possible values of 5 columns of the table. ie: all distinct values of the `name` column.
We expect ~100 different values per column. A `distinct/group by` takes more than 1s per column, making the process not meeting the non functional requirements (process time).
The solution I found was to create a table/view with the `distinct` of each column, that table/view will be refreshed with a cron like task.
Is this the more effective approach to meet the non functional/process time requirement using only postgres tools?

Comment: Do you have an index on each of the columns?

Comment: I would proceed just as you are considering: truncate and fullload a table(not a view!) with distinct values in the background every 5 mins for example and answer the question `distinct/group by` based on the query statistics.

Comment: 5M records is nothing. Please show us the query. (and the table definitions, etc)

Comment: You might want to try GROUP BY instead - Postgres can use a parallel plan for GROUP BY but unfortunately not for DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) that you regularly refresh. Between these refreshes, the data will become slightly stale.

Alternatively, you can maintain a separate table with just the distinct values and use triggers to keep the information up to date whenever rows are modified. This will require a combined index on all the affected columns to be fast.

`DISTINCT` is *always* a performance problem if it affects many rows.